# Runtime Error 3134 Unable to Identify the issue

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I am getting a Runtime Error 3134 on the following code based from an onclick event

```
   strEnt = "INSERT INTO EntList (EntityID, BusinessUnit, EntityName, Position, Location, Client, Dept, DistKey, Salary, Currency, SQ&A, BillRate, Util%, MeritDate, MeritRate) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & Me.EntityID & "', '" & Me.BusinessUnit & "', '" & Me.EntityName & "', '" & Me.Position & "', '" & Me.Location & "', '" & Me.Client & "', '" & Me.Dept & "', '" & Me.DistKey & "', '" & Me.Salary & "', '" & Me.Currency & "', '" & Me.SG_A & "', '" & Me.BillRate & "', '" & Me.Util_ & "', '" & Me.MeritDate & "', '" & Me.Merit_ & "');"
Debug.Print strEnt
CurrentDb.Execute strEnt
```

The debug.print command outputs the following code to the immediate window

```
    INSERT INTO EntList (EntityID, BusinessUnit, EntityName, Position, Location, Client, Dept, DistKey, Salary, Currency, SQ&A, BillRate, Util%, MeritDate, MeritRate) VALUES ('Test10', 'CSS Overhead', 'Walter Tester', 'AutoentryTest', '01002 TELETECH SERVICE CORPORATION', '0001 US LABOR ARB CLIENT', '001 CORPORATE/COMPANY ALLOCATIONS', 'DAE', '250000', 'USD', '0', '300', '1', '', '');
```

Everything Looks like it should work as far as I can tell, can someone help me see what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access SQL that you are trying to execute:

```
INSERT INTO EntList (EntityID, BusinessUnit, EntityName, Position, 
                     Location, Client, Dept, DistKey, Salary, Currency, 
                     SQ&A, BillRate, Util%, MeritDate, MeritRate) 
            VALUES ('Test10', 'CSS Overhead', 'Walter Tester', 'AutoentryTest', 
                    '01002 TELETECH SERVICE CORPORATION', '0001 US LABOR ARB CLIENT', 
                    '001 CORPORATE/COMPANY ALLOCATIONS', 'DAE', '250000', 'USD', '0', 
                    '300', '1', '', '');
```

contains some invalid column name references.  `SQ&A` is definitely not a valid reference, and both `Util%` and `Currency` may also be invalid.  The first two are invalid because they contain characters that are not valid for an unquoted name reference.  And `Currency` *may* be invalid because it may be a reserved word (I am not sure about this one).

The solution to this to just quote them with brackets (`[..]`):

```
INSERT INTO EntList (EntityID, BusinessUnit, EntityName, Position, 
                     Location, Client, Dept, DistKey, Salary, [Currency], 
                     [SQ&A], BillRate, [Util%], MeritDate, MeritRate) 
            VALUES ('Test10', 'CSS Overhead', 'Walter Tester', 'AutoentryTest', 
                    '01002 TELETECH SERVICE CORPORATION', '0001 US LABOR ARB CLIENT', 
                    '001 CORPORATE/COMPANY ALLOCATIONS', 'DAE', '250000', 'USD', '0', 
                    '300', '1', '', '');
```

Comment: `Currency` and `Position` are [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about that. I will check and rerun immediately and comment with the outcome.

Comment: That has it. I also had a few errors where I had incorrectly named some of the columns too. thanks for your help on this one. This of course has allowed me to see the next error which is a runtime error 440 but I will start a new question on that one.